# Use previous value from previous rows for nulls in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fill all null values with the previous value but provided the field account is the same. I have learnt that my table needs to have a Primary Key. At the moment I don't have it on my table and is it possible to create one using the row count of the table, please see below table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ACCOUNT_NO INT, RATE INT, DATE_L DATE, ROWCOUNT INT);    
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 3, '2017-12-31',1);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, NULL, '2018-01-31',2);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 5, '2017-12-31',3);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, NULL, '2018-01-31',4);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, NULL, '2018-02-28',5);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, 2, '2018-03-04',6);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, NULL, '2018-03-04',7);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, 5, '2018-03-04',8);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, NULL, '2018-03-04',9);
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, NULL, '2018-03-04',10);
```

So the table looks like this:

```
|ACCOUNT_NO|RATE|DATE_L    |RowCount|
|1         |3   |2017-12-31|1       |
|1         |NULL|2018-01-31|2       |
|3         |5   |2017-12-31|3       |
|3         |NULL|2018-01-31|4       |
|3         |NULL|2018-02-28|5       |
|6         |2   |2018-03-04|6       |
|6         |NULL|2018-03-04|7       |
|6         |5   |2018-03-04|8       |
|6         |NULL|2018-03-04|9       |
|6         |NULL|2018-03-04|10      |
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
|ACCOUNT_NO|RATE|DATE_L    |RowCount|
|1         |3   |2017-12-31|1       |
|1         |3   |2018-01-31|2       |
|3         |5   |2017-12-31|3       |
|3         |5   |2018-01-31|4       |
|3         |5   |2018-02-28|5       |
|6         |2   |2018-03-04|6       |
|6         |2   |2018-03-04|7       |
|6         |5   |2018-03-04|8       |
|6         |5   |2018-03-04|9       |
|6         |5   |2018-03-04|10      |
```

Any help is welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to SELECT or Update ?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no previous value unless a column in the data specifies the ordering.

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table ? or a datetime column ? Without that, we really cannot define, what is previous and what is next. Data is stored in unordered fashion.

Comment: Please answer the questions asked in the comments above. Your question is incomplete as it stands.

Comment: You have no PK. Without one, this problem is essentially insoluble.

Comment: So I am trying to SELECT. I have added a date column which should help as requested.

Comment: @SIM2000 based on your latest update, there is a problem with the data. For account_no `6` all the dates are same. Due to this, we cannot identify which one is old out of those rows. Are you sure that the fields are just `date` and not `datetime` ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, yes, it is just date. What if we have a row count that counts from 1 till where the data ends, in the example above it will count from 1 to 10 and I use that as my id because it will be unique

Comment: @SIM2000 yes that can be used. Please update the sample data and expected output in the question. I will update my answer which should work for you in this case.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have updated my question above. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @SIM2000 you forgot to update the input data part. It should also have `RowCount` column .

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thank you so much, your solution has worked. Thanks again for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As edited into question later, `ROWCOUNT` column be used to define the "previous/last row". Basic premise is that a lower `ROWCOUNT` value means "older/previous" row.

You can then use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) with conditional [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions to determine the last `NON NULL` value for the same `ACCOUNT_NO`:

**Query**

```
SELECT
  t1.ACCOUNT_NO, 
  CASE WHEN t1.RATE IS NULL 
         THEN (SELECT t2.RATE 
               FROM test AS t2 
               WHERE t2.ROWCOUNT < t1.ROWCOUNT AND 
                     t2.ACCOUNT_NO = t1.ACCOUNT_NO AND 
                     t2.RATE IS NOT NULL 
               ORDER BY t2.ROWCOUNT DESC 
               LIMIT 1)
       ELSE t1.RATE
  END AS RATE, 
  t1.DATE_L, 
  t1.ROWCOUNT 
FROM test AS t1;
```

**Result**

```
| ACCOUNT_NO | DATE_L     | ROWCOUNT | RATE |
| ---------- | ---------- | -------- | ---- |
| 1          | 2017-12-31 | 1        | 3    |
| 1          | 2018-01-31 | 2        | 3    |
| 3          | 2017-12-31 | 3        | 5    |
| 3          | 2018-01-31 | 4        | 5    |
| 3          | 2018-02-28 | 5        | 5    |
| 6          | 2018-03-04 | 6        | 2    |
| 6          | 2018-03-04 | 7        | 2    |
| 6          | 2018-03-04 | 8        | 5    |
| 6          | 2018-03-04 | 9        | 5    |
| 6          | 2018-03-04 | 10       | 5    |
```

---

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMw4sGxxpeznPTQSGtKtSb/1)

Comment: This solution not only assumes that there is a primary key defined, but also that it is an auto increment field.

Comment: @Shadow not necessarily; this solution can work with gaps in the PK. PK requires to be unique (may not necessarily be auto-incremented). Basic premise is that a lower `id` value means "older/previous" row.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya can I use the Date_L as my Primary Key?

Comment: @SIM2000 as discussed in comments above, you can replace `id` with `RowCount` in my query. It shall work for you.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have replaced the id with RowCount but I still get an syntax error 'near LIMIT'. Sorry for the back and forth, I am new to SQL. Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: @SIM2000 Please check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMw4sGxxpeznPTQSGtKtSb/0 ; it is working perfectly fine for me using `ROWCOUNT`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thank you for that, I have found out it is the version of SQL I am using. It does not allow the syntax LIMIT, but should have TOP instead. It seems LIMIT is a MySQL syntax.

Comment: @SIM2000 you are not using a different version; **but you are using a completely different RDBMS, that is, SQL Server**

Answer (score 0):

You problem does not appear to be based on *previous* values, but on non-`NULL` values for the same `account_no`.

```
update test t join
       (select account_no, max(rate) as max_rate
        from test t
        group by account_no
       ) a
       using (account_no)
    set t.rate = a.max_rate
    where t.rate is null;
```

Comment: Check out `account no`=6 rows!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you do a SELECT statement instead of an Update?

Answer (score 0):

Use below simple query. You can get the expected result.

```
UPDATE test AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ACCOUNT_NO, RATE FROM test WHERE RATE !='' GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NO) AS t2 ON t1.ACCOUNT_NO=t2.ACCOUNT_NO
SET t1.RATE=t2.RATE
WHERE t1.RATE IS NULL OR t1.RATE = ''
```

Comment: can you do a SELECT instead of an UPDATE?